# Exist some piece official or unofficial of Lego with the names of the minifigures?

Tags: star-wars, bricklink, bricks-and-pieces

I'm looking for a brick like this:

[image]

Or similar **with the name of the minifigures from the saga star wars**, i want it for my minifigures collection. Exist some like this or an unofficial option?

Answer (score 4):

That part is [Tile 4x4 with studs on edge](https://rebrickable.com/parts/6179/). It's available in many colours but there are only a small number of printed variants. [Rebrickable shows 27 printed variants](https://rebrickable.com/search/?search_type=parts&q=6179pr&part_cat=&exists_in_color=&show_printed=on), 12 of which are Star Wars prints like the one in your question.

I'm not aware of any third-part labels or stickers but you could probably print your own if you're handy with Photoshop or the like. The black unprinted version of that part is [very cheap on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=6179&colorID=11).

Comment: So the viable option is a sticker? don't exist any company or service who printed it? the size of the pieces is not a problem i just want know if exist some service or similar for build it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any information about third-party sticker or printing services. If I were doing this myself I'd create a template and then print off some removable Avery labels or something like that. There _are_, of course, third party companies that would print custom sticker sheets for you, with die-cut stickers or transparency or whatever you're willing to pay for, but I have no idea where you'd go or what that'd cost.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for all the information anyway!!  I will look for a some service like this with the information you have given me.

Comment: @Gawey At least you can buy the 12 existing printed ones! :) Maybe someone else will post something.